# DES ciphertext length decreased during transmission and is not a multiple of 8 bytes

Tags: java, encryption, byte, des

For a project a try to encrypt a pwd with DES algorithm.

When I try this

```
    private static String key = "my8bcode"; /*Key 8 bytes or 56 bit supported by algo OF*/
    private static byte[] byteKey = key.getBytes(); 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
          String ss = "yuyuvdzdsfdsfsdsdsdsdsa";
          byte[] plainText = ss.getBytes();//Conversion en byte

        try {
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(byteKey, "DES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"); // Request the use of the DES algorithm, using the ECB mode (Electronic CodeBook) and style padding PKCS-5.
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
            byte[] myCipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
            System.out.println(new String(myCipherText, "UTF8"));
            System.out.println(myCipherText.length);

             System.out.println("\nStart decryption");
             cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
             byte[] newPlainText = cipher.doFinal(myCipherText);
             System.out.println(new String(newPlainText, "UTF8"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I have no problems, but to go further, i try to do this  in two separate steps with this code :

```
    try {
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(byteKey, "DES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"); //Request the use of the DES algorithm, using the ECB mode (Electronic CodeBook) and style padding PKCS-5.
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
        byte[] myCipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
        byte[] test = (new String(myCipherText, "UTF8")).getBytes();

         System.out.println("\nStart decryption");
         cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
         byte[] newPlainText = cipher.doFinal(test);
         System.out.println(new String(newPlainText, "UTF8"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It doesn't work, i have this message in my console :

> javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8

Indeed, the length of test[] is 7 and not 8. How is possible ?

Why did I lose a byte during my transcription?

Help me please to understand and to solve my problem ;)

Comment: Why the UTF8 encoding of the encrypted byte array?

Comment: What the value of `myCipherText` you enter?

Comment: I see it in an example but i am not sure it's usefull. I will try without it !

Comment: i write it in the first code : String ss = "yuyuvdzdsfdsfsdsdsdsdsa";
          byte[] plainText = ss.getBytes();//Conversion en byte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`byte[]` and `String` should be kept apart. The main error is that a random sequence of bytes (the encrypted text) might easily be **incorrect UTF-8**. UTF-8 is a multi-byte format, where high bits mark a multi-byte sequence in a specified way, `10xxxxxx` being a continuation byte for instance.

However to encrypt a String (Unicode) it is very appropriate to use UTF-8. A single byte encoding would be lossy; say if the text contained both Greek and Bulgarian.

```
byte[] data = text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
text = new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

These are the overloaded versions from the `String` constructor and `getBytes` method, with charset specified. Otherwise it is platform dependent, hence disastrous in communication to another computer.

But as soon as you have binary data, `byte[]`, do not convert it to (Unicode) String, which *is* a (costly) *conversion*, redundant and error prone.

Hence one often sees an additional conversion of the binary data to Base64, receiving a longer ASCII string.

Comment: Thank to You, i have a better vision of getByte method. I will try You way tomorrow, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I just do that (delete UTF 8 specifications) and after lots of test it's working :

```
try {

            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(byteKey, "DES");



            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"); //Demande l'utilisation de l'algorithme DES, en utilisant le mode ECB (Electronic CodeBook) et le style de padding PKCS-5.
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
            byte[] myCipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
            byte[] test = (new String(myCipherText)).getBytes();


             cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
             byte[] newPlainText = cipher.doFinal(test);
             System.out.println(new String(newPlainText));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Thanks a lot